# Can we estimate how many node has the Bitcoin network?

Tags: network, nodes, terminology, hosting

Is it possible to estimate the amount of nodes (hosts) are connected to the Bitcoin network in a given time?

**Note:** Here node means host.

Answer (score 3):

Not very accurately, because it depends on what you consider a node. A host is even more unclear.

- Is it only full nodes?
- Does it include light clients?
- What minimum level of verification must it be doing?
- Must it be listening for peers?

Websites such as [bitnodes.io](https://bitnodes.earn.com/dashboard/?days=365) provide a number of listening nodes, but that doesn't necessarily guarantee that they are operating as such, or doing any transaction verification:

> Bitnodes is currently being developed to estimate the size of the
>   Bitcoin network by finding all the reachable nodes in the network. The
>   current methodology involves sending getaddr messages recursively to
>   find all the reachable nodes in the network, starting from a set of
>   seed nodes. Bitnodes uses Bitcoin protocol version 70001 (i.e. >=
>   /Satoshi:0.8.x/), so nodes running an older protocol version will be
>   skipped. The crawler implementation in Python is available from GitHub
>   (ayeowch/bitnodes) and the crawler deployment is documented in
>   Provisioning Bitcoin Network Crawler.